# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar una fila de una tabla en HTML y que cambie de color al dar click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

> Hola amigos, tengo una tabla en html, pero deseo seleccionar solo la fila y cuando de click cambie de color, alguien puede ayudarme?
> Adjunto el código que tengo.

```
<style>
.selected{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.selected:hover{
    background-color: #0585C0;
    color: white;
}
.seleccionada{
    background-color: #0585C0;
    color: white;
}
.selected{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.selected:hover{
    background-color: #0585C0;
    color: white;
}
.seleccionada{
    background-color: #0585C0;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Por favor añade tu código, este tipo de preguntas no son bien recibidas. Suena a cómo si quisieras que alguien hiciera tu trabajo, en vez de estar buscando ayuda a un problema. Si presentas tu código hasta ahora, vemos que realmente has investigado y estás buscando como corregir las cosas; en vez de pensar que ni si quieras has googleado como "como cambiar el color de mi elemento HTML al hacer click" y vienes aquí buscando alguien que tarde más de lo que tu duras haciendo esa búsqueda para resolver tu problema de una manera fácil. Eso sería sumamente vagabundo.

Comment: Tengo este código, pero no me funciona. La cuestión es que soy nuevo y no sabía como añadir código.

Comment: Esto es extraño porque veo que el 20 de Diciembre habías agregado una pregunta con código, sin embargo, te explico, es muy sencillo, solo tienes que copiar y pegar tu código y luego lo marcas todo con tu mouse y le dás click al botón que tien dos corchetes cerrados (`{ }`). También te sugiero que utilices el botón de "editar" en vez de agregar tu código cómo respuesta, porque esto NO es una respuesta.

Comment: Si añadí una pregunta, pero me quedó mal hecha, y no supe hacer bien la pregunta, como digo apenas empiezo en stackoverflow y poco lo he usado, solo cuando son cosas complejas que no encuentro en internet, y necesito de la sabiduría de aquel que pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El siguiente código te permite seleccionar una fila y al hacer clic nuevamente volver a darle estilos como si fuera una selección.

Puedes tomar la idea y modificarlo según tus necesidades, he utilizado JQuery dado que no lo especificas, pero haz agregado la etiqueta de dicha librería en la publicación.

```js
$(function(){
  $('tr').click(function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass('row-selected')){
      $(this).addClass('other-clic')
    }else{
      cleanTr()
      $(this).addClass('row-selected')
    }
  })
  
  
  function cleanTr(){
    $('.row-selected').each(function(index, element){
      $(element).removeClass('row-selected')
      $(element).removeClass('other-clic')
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.row-selected{
  background: yellow;
}


.other-clic{
  background: green !important;
  color: white;
}

tr{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="default">
  <tr>
    <td>Celda 1</td>
    <td>Celda 2</td>
    <td>Celda 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Celda 4</td>
    <td>Celda 5</td>
    <td>Celda 6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tendré en cuenta las sugerencias que han hecho a cerca de como realizo las preguntas. Como digo soy nuevo en esto, pero nuevamente gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Tranquilo, nadie nace sabiendo y todo se puede aprender!! Si quieres familiarizarte más con Stackoverflow te recomiendo leer [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Muchas gracias Cesar. :)